# Must Declare a static variable in c# Winfoms

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have got an error that you must have to declare a static variable @campus_id. I don't know how to declare and where to declare and what it means to declare a static variable. Help me please!

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        CS = ConfigurationManager
                   .ConnectionStrings["UMSdbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                "SELECT ISNULL(MAX(campus_id),0)+1 FROM Campus", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            tbCampusID.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(
              "INSERT INTO Campus (campus_id,campus_name)VALUES(@camp_id,camp_name)", con))
            {
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@campus_id", tbCampusID.Text);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@campus_name", tbCampusName.Text);
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Saved");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not have to declare @Winforms.... Your receiving an SQL error..? right??

Comment: Do not tell us about the error, quote it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding value to a placeholder that is not yet defined. see this statement 
`cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@campus_id", tbCampusID.Text);` Here you are using `campus_id` as placeholder and take a look into the insert query, ie., `INSERT INTO Campus (campus_id,campus_name)VALUES(@camp_id,camp_name)`. and there the placeholder is `camp_id` and that causing the error; use like this:

```
string querySql = "INSERT INTO Campus (campus_id, campus_name) VALUES(@camp_id, @campus_name)"
using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(querySql, con))
{
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@camp_id", tbCampusID.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@campus_name", tbCampusName.Text);
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter names in your SQL query and in the call to `Parameters.AddWithValue` must match:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO Campus (campus_id, campus_name) VALUES(@campus_id, @campus_name)", con))
{
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@campus_id", tbCampusID.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@campus_name", tbCampusName.Text);
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```